# EXT Js Panel Resize

Tags: extjs, resize, panel

I want my ext js panel to be resizable, i.e when I put my mouse over the panel it must show

me the resize controls. How do I do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ext.Resizable. Check this link:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/resizer/basic.html

Edit: Link updated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't resize the panel component, you resize whatever it is contained within.

If you have the panel in a window object, you resize the window and the panel will resize with it automatically; unless you have specified height/width figures specifically which disables the layout manager from handling it.

Comment: is it possible to add a window to a panel ?

Comment: You can open up a window inside of a panel, but the original panel still needs to be within a container if you want to monitor resizing.  If your main application needs to be just a stand alone panel, it still should be inside of some other container.  (Maybe a Viewport?)  

Swar's link looks like it would work too, I wasn't aware of that component.

Answer (score 0):

```
    resizable: true,
```

Panels accept a "resizable" attribute that will automatically display Ext.resizer.Resizer handles around the panel.